# Proper method to get the latest npm on macOS?

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, upgrade

When I did `npm -v` it showed version 7.something.
I just wanted to make sure I have the latest available, so I did `npm install -g npm`.

It seemed to work OK (it did go through a install/upgrade process) but when I now do `npm -v` it says `6.14.9`.

What is the 'correct' or proper way to get the latest npm on macOS? And I mean in a global way (for my entire coding environment) so that any NodeJS project in any directory will universally use the latest npm.

FYI I'm using macOS Catalina 10.15.6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`npm` 7 ships with Node.js 15.x but is not yet the default `latest` within the `npm` registry. Confusing! If you want the latest 7.x version of `npm`, you need to specify that you want version 7:  `npm install -g npm@7`. Otherwise, it will give you the latest 6.x release.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to manage your node versions. It allows switching between projects with different versions without running into version issues.

With it, you can use `nvm install node` to install the latest one, or `nvm ls-remote` to list available versions for install.